# Mathematica HPC on AWS vs. Azure

Tags: parallelization, webservices, cloud-deploy, high-performance-clusters

I am looking for advice on deploying Mathematica for HPC in an on-demand cloud environment.  I occasionally have Mathematica projects that require parallel computing and large amounts of RAM.  These generally involve clustering, multi-dimensional scaling, geospatial transformation of large lists and geospatial plotting.  I am currently running Mathematica 10.4 on an academic HPC network, but have real trouble getting the configuration I need at any reasonable priority (12 cores, 256 GB RAM, GPU array, SSD working drive).  I am looking at deploying on AWS or Azure.

Does anybody have experience with either service?

How is the Mathematica licensing handled (is it machine locked requiring a dedicated server?)

Any recommendations for OS?  (Linux vs. Windows Server...I know, but I had to ask)

Thanks!

Comment: This is a question I am also interested in, but I am not sure this is the right forum. Probably, [community.wolfram.com](http://community.wolfram.com/) is better. Also, have you had a similar set up with other systems / languages before? E.g. Python or R with Spark on AWS?

Comment: @Karsten 7 What advice do you have about this?

Comment: No new advice.  Given the MMA machine-locked licensing issues, I gave up on this a while ago.